# R function that returns altered data for grouped variables

Tags: r, function, dataframe

I have a simple example to explain my problem: lets say I use the mtcars dataframe. And I would like to alter the data of `mtcars$qsec` by using the following function:

```
TT.test <- function(x)
{
  x<- ifelse(x > 20,x,NA)
  return(x)
}
```

The catch is I want to alter the `mtcars$qsec` using this function by grouping on `mtcars$gear` and `mtcars$cyl`. So I would like to get a dataframe or matrix that gives me a dataframe back with the altered data. It is fine if the dataframe only contains the three columns considered.

Do you have any suggestions on how to deal with this problem?

Comment: can you provide an example of the output expected? How is it relevant that you do the alteration grouping on other columns if the function does not consider other values than the one to be modified?

Comment: I would like the same output as given by user3949008, however it doesn't seem to work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to mutate just that column, and group by some others, here is how you can do it with dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>% group_by(gear, cyl) %>% mutate(qsec = TT.test(qsec))
```

Here is the resulting output:

```
Source: local data frame [32 x 11]
Groups: gear, cyl [8]

     mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
   (dbl) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl)
1   21.0     6 160.0   110  3.90 2.620    NA     0     1     4     4
2   21.0     6 160.0   110  3.90 2.875    NA     0     1     4     4
3   22.8     4 108.0    93  3.85 2.320    NA     1     1     4     1
4   21.4     6 258.0   110  3.08 3.215    NA     1     0     3     1
5   18.7     8 360.0   175  3.15 3.440    NA     0     0     3     2
6   18.1     6 225.0   105  2.76 3.460 20.22     1     0     3     1
7   14.3     8 360.0   245  3.21 3.570    NA     0     0     3     4
8   24.4     4 146.7    62  3.69 3.190    NA     1     0     4     2
9   22.8     4 140.8    95  3.92 3.150 22.90     1     0     4     2
10  19.2     6 167.6   123  3.92 3.440    NA     1     0     4     4
..   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...
```

If you want to mutate all columns, you can do something like this:

```
mtcars %>% group_by(gear, cyl) %>% mutate_each(funs(TT.test))
```

OR if you want to mutate some select columns (multiple), you can do something like this:

```
mtcars %>% group_by(gear, cyl) %>% mutate_each(funs(TT.test), c(qsec, hp))
```

Comment: I did not copy your function into my answer. Of course, you will need to use that piece of code as well. :)

Comment: Thank you, your answer almost helps me.  When I run the code, I get in every cell a vector of type double which has the transformed data for each grouping combination. However I would like to have just 1 observation per cell of the dataframe containing the transformed data. For Example

Comment: cyl  disp   drat    wt      qsec   am  gear  
    (dbl) (dbl)  (dbl) (dbl)     (chr)  (dbl) (dbl) 
1      6 160.0    3.90 2.620  <dbl[4]>      1     4     
2      6 160.0    3.90 2.875  <dbl[4]>      1     4     
3      4 108.0    3.85 2.320  <dbl[8]>       1     4

Comment: I just added the output I get when I run that command. Not sure why you are seeing a vector of doubles.

Comment: Which code did you use? because that output is exactly what I need

Comment: One under which I posted the output. The first line.

Comment: When I do yours I get: Error: object 'sec' not found. If I replace sec with qsec, I get the a vector of doubles

Comment: Sorry...stupid autocorrect. It changed qsec to sec. It should be qsec.

Comment: It's really odd that for all the different codes you shared with me, all of them give a vector of doubles instead of the desired output. I will try to reinstall the dplyr package, maybe that will help